# .yarnrc for Mac and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, unix, filesystems, yarnpkg

I have a `.yarnrc` file with a Windows path in it.

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1


yarn-offline-mirror "C:\\yarn-offline-mirror"
yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true
```

This project is shared between Windows and Mac users though.

Can I craft a file path that will work for both?